# Using printers on Yocto

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, yocto, cups

Some days ago I decided to us Yocto for running my custom photo booth application on a Raspberry Pi. Main reason why choosing Yocto was the lack of a recent QT version on Raspbian which was needed by some features. Other solution didn't offer a hardware acceleration.

After getting the most features running, I stopped at the problem getting the printer configured and running. Cups seems to be sane and running corrently.

My goal was, that the printer is set up at first login by a profile.d-script. I'm using the lpadmin command:

```
# Check to see if the printer is already installed
if [ `lpstat -p 2>&1 | grep -E 'CP910' -c || true` = "0" ]
then
    echo "Installing CP910"
    lpadmin -p CP910 -E -m /usr/share/cups/ppd/Canon_CP910.ppd -v usb://Canon/CP910?serial=C91xxxxxxx
    lpadmin -d CP910
    cupsenable
fi
```

I copied the PPD file from my Ubuntu computer. lpadmin issues no error. lpstat -v lists my added printer. The output of lpstat -v looks on both Ubuntu and Yocto the same.

When trying to print any file, the state stays at "sending data" and nothing happens.

I have seen that there are cups-filters and drivers. I haven't found any recipes for filters and drivers for Yocto. So I assume that everything is shipped with the CUPS recipt?

Comment: i have got same issue, if you solved this issue please let me know,what is sol

Comment: I kind of solved the problem:
The problem is, that CUPS requires printer drivers. The collection of printer drivers is called Gutenprint. So I tried to build a recipe for Gutenprint. But there are a lot of dependencies which I didn't manage to resolve. So I did another approach:
There is a program, which is able to start a print job over Wifi. I have a fork of this program on github: https://github.com/saeugetier/go-selphy-cp. You can start a print job via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Besides CUPS also Gutenprint is needed. Gutenprint provides the printer drivers. Without Gutenprint, CUPS can not connect to the printer.
Yocto currently has no recipe for Gutenprint. Maybe you are lucky and someone will write a recipe soon.

The CP910 can print via Wifi. Fortunately, there is a program that can start printing jobs via Wifi: https://github.com/saeugetier/go-selphy-cp